# Basic authentication IHttpModule unexpected behaviour

Tags: asp.net, basic-authentication

I have enabled Basic Authentication in IIS7 for my site and followed this [link](http://blog.smithfamily.dk/2008/08/27/ImplementingBasicAuthenticationInASPNET20.aspx) to create handler for basic authentication requests.
The problem is that no matter what credentials user enters, the site keeps returning 401, even if entering correct credentials.  This is just a test and credentials are checked against hardcoded values.

Here is relevant code:

```
  public class BasicAuthenticationHttpModule : IHttpModule 
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest+=context_BeginRequest;
        context.AuthenticateRequest += context_AuthenticateRequest;
    }

    void context_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;

        TryAuthenticate(application);
    }

    private void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;

        TryAuthenticate(application);
    }

    private static void TryAuthenticate(HttpApplication application)
    {
        if (!Authenticate(application.Context))
        {
            application.Context.Response.Status = "401 Unauthorized";
            application.Context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            application.Context.Response.AddHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic");
            application.CompleteRequest();
        }
    }

    private static bool Authenticate(HttpContext context)
    {            
        if (context.User!=null && context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (!context.Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Authorization"))
            return false;

        string authHeader = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

        IPrincipal principal;
        if (TryGetPrincipal(authHeader, out principal))
        {
            context.User = principal; 
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static bool TryGetPrincipal(string[] creds, out IPrincipal principal)
    {
        if (creds[0] == "Administrator" && creds[1] == "SecurePassword")
        {
            principal = new GenericPrincipal(
               new GenericIdentity("Administrator"),
               new string[] { "Administrator", "User" }
            );
            return true;
        }
        if (creds[0] == "BasicUser" && creds[1] == "Password")
        { 
            principal = new GenericPrincipal(
               new GenericIdentity("BasicUser"),
               new string[] { "User", "SystemUser" }
            );
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            principal = null;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

When client enters correct credentials (i.e. "BasicUser", "Password"), GenericPrincipal object is created and assigned to HttpContext's User property.  Looking into Request.IsAuthenticated tells that it's `true`.

And this is why I don't understand is why client receives 401 again and again and again.
I'm not sure how all the pipeline works - may be basic authentication goes further to some IIS HttpModule which also serves the request?  Or may be code is incomplete and `context_BeginRequest` needs to be extended?  (I know that in case of Forms authentication type, you do something like Response.Redirect(goodguy.aspx))

Anyway, any help/questions are appreciated.

Forgot to mention that in web.config I also placed

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="BasicAuthenticationHttpModule" type="Analytics.BasicAuthenticationHttpModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently implemements it's own Basic authentication.  Thus our module could authenticate request succussfully, it would get passed to built-in IIS module, which rejected authentication. It is really helpful not to copy paste, but also to think yourself indeed.  So to answer my question - disable all authentication on IIS except Anonymous.